OKX error {'msg': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', 'code': '50112'}
Issue with Timestamp Expiry Error
Hello Forum Members,
I'm encountering an issue with my Python code while interfacing with the OKEx API. Specifically, I'm receiving a {'msg': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', 'code': '50112'}. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code snippet:
class OkexBot:
    def init(self, APIKEY: str, APISECRET: str, PASS: str):
        self.apikey = APIKEY
        self.apisecret = APISECRET
        self.password = PASS
        self.baseURL = 'https://www.okex.com'

    @staticmethod
    def get_time():
        time_cur = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc).isoformat("T", "milliseconds") + 'Z'
        return time_cur


    @staticmethod
    def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body, secret_key):
        message = timestamp + method + request_path + body
        mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
        output = mac.digest()
        return base64.b64encode(output)

    def get_header(self, request='GET', endpoint='', body=''):
        cur_time = self.get_time()
        header = dict()
        header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = "application/json"
        header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = APIKEY
        header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = self.signature(cur_time, request, endpoint, body, APISECRET)
        header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(cur_time)
        header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = PASS
        return header

    def withdrawal(self,  account, amount):
        endpoint = '/api/v5/asset/withdrawal'
        url = self.baseURL + endpoint
        request = 'POST'
        body = {
            "amt": str(amount),
            "fee": "0.0096",
            "dest": "4",
            "ccy": "SOL",
            "chain": "SOL-Solana",
            "toAddr": account
        }
        body = json.dumps(body)
        header = self.get_header(request, endpoint, str(body))
        response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=body)
        return response

I changed the way to get the current time

i find this solve
 // Method to get the current UTC timestamp with millisecond precision
    public static String getCurrentUTCTimestamp() {
        return java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                .withZone(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .format(java.time.Instant.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MILLIS));

